# Why is the background of my table view grey when there are no rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why is the background of my table view grey when there are no rows? I can't see where this is set in storyboard

[image: screenshot]

Even setting the background to white explicitly I still get a grey background

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Using the defaults for background also results in this grey background:

[image: Defaults]

Comment: probably it's background Color!

Comment: ctrl + shift + left click on your view and select your table view.Then from Attributes Inspector you can select background color from 'View' section.If this is not the case, check your code for possible background color setups.

Comment: please show us your `UITableViewCell` if my post shouldn't work, its possible you make changes in code which will cause the backgroundcolor to switch to grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be due to two reason

a) you haven't set data source and delegate and your main view background color is gray

b) cell background color is gray, set that to clear color

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code viewdidload or viewwillappear method

```
table.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like it is a problem of the `UITableViewCells`, you should set them to

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // or clearColor
```

then also set the `UITableView` itself inside the controller to backgroundColor white or grey.

Also the snippet of @Rohitsuvagiya can help to let dissappear the separators if there is no additional `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add line your code in viewdidload or viewillappear

```
table.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```